# Using "is default" with Hash of Arrays

Tags: raku

Here is the working example:

```raku
my %hash;
for 1..4 -> $i {
    %hash{$i} = Array.new without %hash{$i};
    %hash{$i}.push: $_ for ^$i;
}
say %hash; # OUTPUT: {1 => [0], 2 => [0 1], 3 => [0 1 2], 4 => [0 1 2 3]}
```

But why the next similar example doesn't work?

```raku
my %hash is default(Array.new);
for 1..4 -> $i {
    %hash{$i}.push: $_ for ^$i;
}
say %hash; # OUTPUT: {}
```

This even more confuses me, because the next example works as expected:

```raku
my %hash is default(42);
for 1..4 -> $i {
    %hash{$i}.=Str;
}
say %hash.raku; # OUTPUT: {"1" => "42", "2" => "42", "3" => "42", "4" => "42"}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not immediately clear to me why the result of the second example is an empty hash, however using `is default` like this is not going to work as you wish. Traits are applied at compile time; thus `is default(Array.new)`, even if it worked correctly, would create a single `Array` instance at compile time, and reuse it globally. So the output I'd expect is something like:

```
1 => [0 0 1 0 1 2 0 1 2 3], 2 => [0 0 1 0 1 2 0 1 2 3], 3 => [0 0 1 0 1 2 0 1 2 3], 4 => [0 0 1 0 1 2 0 1 2 3]}
```

That it doesn't give this is probably a bug.

However, thanks to auto-vivification, the first example can be reduced to:

```
my %hash;
for 1..4 -> $i {
    %hash{$i}.push: $_ for ^$i;
}
say %hash; # {1 => [0], 2 => [0 1], 3 => [0 1 2], 4 => [0 1 2 3]}
```

The array is created automatically when doing an array operation on an undefined value anyway, thus meaning there's no use for `is default` in this kind of situation.

Comment: I guess in RakuAST we could pretty easily consider the contents of `is default()` as a thunk, and codegen it to run it at runtime with a special Container Descriptor?  I've had cases where I wanted to force the values of a hash e.g. to be a native `str` array, and it would be handy for that.

Comment: I don't think RakuAST by itself changes anything much here. Traits are implemented as a multiple dispatch executed at compile time, and so by the time we reach the trait handler we've already got the value, not the AST. I don't really see why one would special-case `is default` when there's already the `will` trait that comes with a block, so a `will default { ... }` wouldn't need a special-case.